# How to find array elements that are the sum of a given number

Tags: arrays, ruby

For example, we have such array `arr = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7]` and we have given number 8, we need to find any n number of elements in this array that will be the sum of the given number. In this case, it should be [1, 3, 4] or [1, 7] or [3, 5]. What is the easiest way to do it in Ruby?

Comment: Sounds like homework

Comment: Use [`combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) to get the combinations of a given length and select those with a sum of 8, e.g. `arr.combination(2).select { |c| c.sum == 8 }` returns `[[1, 7], [1, 7], [3, 5]]`, i.e. all pairs with a sum of 8. (the combination `[1, 7]`) appears twice because you have two `1`'s in your array)

Comment: This is called the *Subset-Sum Problem* and is NP-complete. In other words, *there is no easy way* to do it *at all*, not just in Ruby. ("easy" in the sense of "efficient".)

Comment: It's not homework, that was some part of discount logic on as simple as possible example

Comment: @JörgWMittag, NP-complete, yes, but depending on the size of the given total and the size of the array of possible summands, a dynamic programming solution such as the one I have provided can be much faster than a brute-force enumeration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Stefan and @Jorg said in comments there is no easy way to do it. If this was a question to myself, I would probably write down something like this.

```rb
arr = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
number = 8
result = []

for i in 0..(arr.length) do
  arr.combination(i).each do |combination|
    result.push(combination) if combination.sum == number
  end
end

print result.uniq
```

Comment: Without uniq result will be ```[[1, 7], [1, 7], [3, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4]]```. It's given all possible result set, you can choose any from it. I changed the first part to your suggestion by the way, thanks! @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the magnitude of the given number, it may be faster to use dynamic programming. If `tot` is the given number and `arr` is the array of possible summands, the method given below has a computational complexity of `O(tot*arr.size)`.

**Code**

```
def find_summands(arr, tot)
  return [] if tot.zero?
  arr.each_with_object([{tot=>nil}]) do |n,a|
    h = a.last.each_key.with_object({}) do |t,h|
      return soln(arr,a.drop(1),n) if t==n
      h[t] = 0
      h[t-n] = n
    end
    a << h
  end
  nil
end
```

```
def soln(arr,a,n)
  t = n      
  a.reverse.each_with_object([n]) do |h,b|
    m = h[t]
    b << m 
    t += m
  end.reverse.tap { |a| (arr.size-a.size).times { a << 0 } }
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

```
find_summands(arr, 8)
  #=> [1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0] 
find_summands(arr, 11)
  #=> [1, 1, 0, 4, 5, 0] 
find_summands(arr, 21)
  #=> [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7] 
find_summands(arr, 22)
  #=> nil
find_summands([1, -2, 3, 4, 5, 7], 6)
  #=> [1, -2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
```

Each zero in the array returned indicates that the corresponding element in `arr` is not used in the summation.

**Explanation**

Suppose:

```
arr = [4, 2, 6, 3, 5, 1]
tot = 13
```

then

```
find_summands(arr, tot)
  #=> [4, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0]
```

When a solution is obtained `soln` is called to put it into a more useful form:

```
soln(arr, a.drop(1), n)
```

Here, `arr` is as above and

```
n #=> 3 
a #=> [
  {13=>nil},                                    # for tot
  {13=>0,  9=>4},                               # for arr[0] => 4
  {13=>0, 11=>2,  9=>0, 7=>2},                  # for arr[1] => 2
  {13=>0,  7=>0, 11=>0, 5=>6, 9=>0, 3=>6, 1=>6} # for arr[2] => 6
]
```

`n` equals the value of the last summand used from `arr`, left to right.

When considering `arr[0] #=> 4` the remaining amount to be summed is `13`, the key of `a[0] #=> {13=>nil}`. There are two possibilities, `4` is a summand or it is not. This gives rise to the hash

```
a[1]
  #=> {13-0=>0, 13-4=>4}
  #   {  13=>0,    9=>4}
```

where the keys are the remaining amount to be summed and the value is `4` if `4` is a summand and is zero if it is not.

Now consider `arr[1] #=> 2`. We look to the keys of `a[1]` to see what the possible remaining amounts might be after `4` is used or not. (`13` and `9`). For each of these we consider using or not using `2`. That gives rise to the hash

```
a[2]
  #=> {13-0=>0, 13-2=>2, 9-0=>0, 9-2=>2}
  #   {  13=>0,   11=>2,   9=>0,   7=>2}
```

`7=>2` can be read, if `2` (the value) is a summand, there is a choice of using `arr[0]` or not that results in the remaining amount to be summed after `2` is included being `7`.

Next consider `arr[2] #=> 6`. We look to the keys of `a[2]` to see what the possible remaining amounts might be after `4` and `6` are used or not. (`13`, `11`, `9` and `7`). For each of these we consider using or not using `6`. We therefore now create the hash

```
a[3]
  #=> {13-0=>0, 13-6=>6, 11-0=>0, 11-6=>6, 9-0=>0, 9-6=>6, 7-0=>0, 7-6=>6}
  #   {  13=>0,    7=>6,   11=>0,    5=>6,   9=>0,   3=>6,   7=>0,   1=>6}
  #   {  13=>0,            11=>0,    5=>6,   9=>0,   3=>6,   7=>0,   1=>6}
```

The pair `11=>0` can be read, "if `6` is not a summand, there is a choice of using or not using `arr[0] #=> 4` and `arr[2] #=> 2` that results in the remaining amount to be summed after `6` is excluded being `11`".

Note that the key-value pair `7=>6` was overwritten with `7=>0` when not using `6` was considered with a remaining amount of `7`. We are only looking for one solution, so it doesn't matter how we get to a remaining amount of `7` after the first three elements of `arr` are considered. These *collisions* tend to increase as we move left-to-right in `arr`, so the number of states we need to keep track of is greatly reduced because we are able to "throw away" so many of them.

Lastly (as it turns out), we consider `arr[3] #=> 3`. We look to the keys of `a[3]` to see what the possible remaining amounts might be after `4`, `2` and `6` have been used or not (`13`, `11`, `5`, `9`, `3`, `7` and `1`). For each of these we consider using or not using `3`. We get this far in creating the hash `a[4]`:

```
{13=>0, 10=>3, 11=>0, 8=>3, 5=>0, 2=>3, 9=>0, 6=>3, 3=>0, 0=>3}
```

As the last key-value pair has a key of zero we know we have found a solution.

Let's construct the solution. Because the value of `0` is `3`, `3` is a summand. (We would have found the solution earlier if the value were zero.) We now work backwards. As `3` is used, the remaining amount before `3` is used is `0+3 #=> 3`. We find that `a[3][3] #=> 6`, meaning `6` is also a summand. The remaining balance before using the `6` was `3+6 #=> 9`, so we compute `a[2][9] #=> 0`, which tells us that the `2` is not a summand. Lastly, `a[1][9-0] #=> 4` shows that `4` is also a summand. Hence the solution

```
[4, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0]
```